# Bob Shaw short story, set in the Old West, a woman from the future takes refuge in the past, meets a man who has semi-crippled arms

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Set in the Old West, a woman from the future takes refuge in the past to escape from (?) She elicits help from a local who makes peyote? He also has semi-crippled arms from a past encounter with local ruffians. He helps her fight off the bad guy from the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [Skirmish on a Summer Morning](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93680).

> Greg had emerged from the encounter with crippled arms and a new habit
> of planning his every move with the thoughtfulness of a chess master.